# Spring Statemachine persister for spring data

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

We are currently investigating spring state machine and we have a very similar need to the eventservice sample with a pool and context switching using a repository, the only problem is redis is linux only (for production) and we can not lean on that... is there a clean out-of-the-box way to integrate persistence using spring data or will i have to write my own implementation for StateMachinePersister.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/master/spring-statemachine-samples/eventservice/src/main/java/demo/eventservice

should i go about using AbstractStateMachinePersister or StateMachinePersist?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB spring data integration so you need to use low level API's to build your own persist impl. Having said that, spring data support has been in my mind but just haven't had time to push it forward. PR's highly appreciated ;)

`StateMachinePersister` is an interface to follow which `AbstractStateMachinePersister` implements.